# Can a fielder get a run-out by removing bails or stumps with their upper arm or shoulder?

Tags: rules, cricket

During a run-out attempt, removing the bails using the hands holding the ball is a valid run-out.

But when a fielder removes the bails or stumps using his elbow or shoulder, is it still a valid dismissal?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is explicitly allowed by the [Laws of Cricket](https://www.lords.org/mcc/all-laws); quoting from Law 29 "The Wicket is Down":

> 29.1.1 The wicket is put down if a bail is completely removed from the top of the stumps, or a stump is struck out of the ground,
>
> [...]
>
> 29.1.1.5 by a fielder with his/her hand **or arm**, providing that the ball is held in the hand or hands so used, or in the hand of the arm so used.

(my emphasis).

Comment: The latest update to lords.org has made it very hard to find/link to the specific Laws. I'll update this answer if I find a way to do it, or anyone else feel free to propose an edit...

Comment: I think it's perfectly adequate to cite the law (and exact section(s) as appropriate) and allow users to make their own way to Lords.org if they want to check. It's not like the new interface is confusing or difficult.